# How to link front end to back end?

Tags: python, vue.js, web, frontend, backend

I am a complete beginner when it comes to web development. I want to create a web page using VueJS. if you click on a button "move", it communicates with a python code that will move a motor (I am using a raspberry pi 4) for a few seconds and if we click on the button "stop", it stops the motor. The status of the motor is then updated on the page to "moving" or "stopped".
The thing is, I don't know how to link the 2 programs. Do you know how I could do that?

Here is the code of my vue app:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      neutral: true,
      open: false,
      close: false,
      opened: false,
      closed: true,
      titleClass: 'title',
      title2Class: 'title2',
      btnClass: 'btn'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.open = true
      this.close= false
      this. neutral=false
    },
    toggle2(){
      this.open = false
      this.close= true
      this. neutral=false
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="body">
    <h1 v-if="opened" :class="titleClass"> Status: moving</h1>
    <h1 v-else-if="closed" :class="title2Class"> Status: stopped</h1>
    <button @click="toggle" :class="btnClass">Move</button>
    <button @click="toggle2" :class="btnClass">Stop</button>
    <br>
    <h1 v-if="open">Request sent: Move</h1>
    <h1 v-else-if="close"> Request sent: Stop</h1>
    <h1 v-else="neutral">No request sent.</h1>
    <br>
    <h2 v-if="open || close">Waiting for response...</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <img src="logo.png" class="logo">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And here is the code that moves my motor:

```
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

if __name__=="__main__":
  GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
  GPIO.setup(10,GPIO.OUT)
  
  servo=GPIO.PWM(10,100)
  servo.start(0)
  #the received command is sys.argv[1]
  if sys.argv[1]=="move":
    servo.ChangeDutyCycle(8)
    time.sleep(5)
  else:
    servo.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
    time.sleep(5)
  servo.stop()
  GPIO.cleanup()
  print("end")
```

Comment: Not sure about the python side, but why not to use http request?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Python Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/) to create an HTTP microsever and map your python code to specific routes, which you can then call from your Vue app (for example using [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).